# React Router using createBrowserRouter vs BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am starting a new React project and want to use the latest version of React Router. The docs recommend using `createBrowserRouter` for all web projects. They don't say why it is better than using `BrowserRouter`other than it enables some data APIs. Is this the only advantage.

Additionally there is a note in the docs saying

```
Due to the decoupling of fetching and rendering in the design of the data APIs, you should create your router outside of the React tree with a statically defined set of routes. For more information on this design, please see the Remixing React Router blog post and the When to Fetch conference talk.
```

I'm not exactly sure what they mean by `outside the React tree` isn't everything in my project in the React tree.

Currently I am implementing my router like this:

Main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <GenReMsal>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GenReMsal>
)
```

App.js

```
function App({ msalContext }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <Router currentUser={msalContext.accounts[0]} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
    </>
  )
}
```

Router.js

```
function Router({ currentUser }: Props) {
  const userInfo = { name: currentUser.name }

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId?',
      element: <AppLayout currentUser={userInfo} />,
      loader: defaulNewAPIs,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ])

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}
```

This doesn't seem to be outside the React tree but I am not exactly sure what would.

Comment: Please ask **one** question per question, not more than one.

Comment: Re your second question, *"I'm not exactly sure what they mean by outside the React tree..."*, they mean in code that isn't in a component. For instance, code in `main.tsx` that you run prior to calling `render` on the root. (It doesn't have to be `main.tsx`, it just has to be not in a component.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how would this be possible when I need my router to be wrapped in the `<AuthenticationTemplate/>` component

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router), it looks like you use `RouterProvider` there, passing in the router you created outside it, rather than using `Router`. But I haven't used the latest yet, I was just explaining what they meant in that sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Additionally there is a note in the docs saying
>
> > Due to the decoupling of fetching and rendering in the design of the
> > data APIs, you should create your router outside of the React tree
> > with a statically defined set of routes. For more information on this
> > design, please see the Remixing React Router blog post and the When to
> > Fetch conference talk.
>
> I'm not exactly sure what they mean by outside the React tree isn't
> everything in my project in the React tree.

What this basically means is that is it recommended to create the router ***outside*** any React component such that it is a stable reference.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...routes...
]);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

In your implementation the `router` is created ***inside*** the `Router` component.

```
function Router({ currentUser }: Props) {
  const userInfo = { name: currentUser.name }

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId?',
      element: <AppLayout currentUser={userInfo} />,
      loader: defaulNewAPIs,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

`Router` is rendered by `App`.

```
function App({ msalContext }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <Router currentUser={msalContext.accounts[0]} />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any time a component higher up in the ReactTree than `Router`, e.g. `AuthenticatedTemplate` or `App`, rerenders, their entire sub-ReactTree is rerendered. What this means in `Router` now is that the `router` will be redeclared and a new reference and this will ***necessarily*** remount any of the routed components that may be rendered.

Since your router appears to have a dependency on the `currentUser` prop a solution here could be to memoize the `router` value.

```
function Router({ currentUser }: Props) {
  const router = React.useMemo(() => {
    return createBrowserRouter([
      {
        path: '/:appTypeId?',
        element: <AppLayout currentUser={{ name: currentUser.name }} />,
        loader: defaulNewAPIs,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  }, [currentUser]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

A better solution however would be to provide the `currentUser` or the entire `msalContext` value via a React context to your app and decouple if from your routing logic.

Example:

```
const MsalContext = React.createContext( .... );

const useMsalContext = () => React.useContext();

const MsalContextProvider = ({ children, msalContext }) => {
  return (
    <MsalContext.Provider value={msalContext}>
      {children}
    </MsalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
function App({ msalContext }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <MsalContextProvider msalContext={msalContext}>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <Router />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
    </MsalContextProvider>
  )
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/:appTypeId?',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    loader: defaulNewAPIs,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function Router() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

```
const AppLayout = () => {
  const {
    accounts: [
      { name } // msalContext.accounts[0].name -> name
    ]
  } = useMsalContext();

  ...
};
```