React "useAuth" hook not correctly retrieving "isAdmin" status asynchronously
I'm currently implementing authentication in my React application using a custom useAuth hook. The hook retrieves the user's authentication status and isAdmin status from a JWT token stored in localStorage. However, I'm encountering an issue where the isAdmin status is not correctly retrieved asynchronously. After logging in, the isAdmin status is sometimes incorrect or not updated until a page reload. I've tried adding a loading state to handle asynchronous operations, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. How can I ensure that the isAdmin status is correctly retrieved asynchronously without requiring a page reload? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
useAuth hook
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const useAuth = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(token);
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, [token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchToken = () => {
      if (token) {
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);

        if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 > Date.now()) {
          setIsAdmin(decodedToken.isAdmin);
        }
      } else {
        setIsAdmin(false);
      }
    };

    fetchToken();
  }, [token]);

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("userId");
    setIsAdmin(false);
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  };

  return { logoutHandler, isLoggedIn, isAdmin };
};

export default useAuth;

App.jsx
function App() {
  const { isAdmin } = useAuth();  //This is retrieved asynchronously
 
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <RootLayout />,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <HomePage />, loader: fetchMealsLoader },
        { path: "auth/signup", element: <SignupPage />, action: signUpAction },
        { path: "auth/login", element: <LoginPage />, action: loginAction },
        {
          path: "admin",
          element: isAdmin ? <AdminPage /> : <NotAdminError />,
          loader: adminMealsLoader,
          action: sendMealDataAction,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;


A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887755/7545496 - the problem might be related to the declaration of the routes inside a React component, rather than to the asynchronous retrieval of the JWT token

There is no asynchronous code in the example you shared. When a user logs in what exactly are you expecting to happen in the code you shared here? Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific issue is in better detail.
